# How to use multiple expressions in onClick?

Tags: reactjs

A syntax question when inserting two expressions in onClick.

With one expression, this works:
`<Button onClick={this.A}>Push me</Button>`

But when I add a second expression in the following ways, it no longer works:
`<Button onClick={this.A; this.B;}>Push me</Button>`
or 
`<Button onClick={() => {this.A; this.B;}}>Push me</Button>`
or
`<Button onClick={() => {this.A(); this.B()}}>Push me</Button>`

tia

Comment: without more code it's really hard to give you an answer...let show use the A and B functions, for instance.

Comment: show us your error

Comment: normally， `<Button onClick={() => {this.A(); this.B()}}>Push me</Button>` should able to work